# Hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, switch

I am going from a tank to a tankless water heater.

Can I cap off the 3rd copper pipe coming out of center of existing tank.

The Tankless unit has only a hot and a cold, nothing for recirculating.

Will it cause problems to cap the 3rd pipe?

Comment: More info is needed on your system. Make & model, photo of your old set up would help. Are you saying you have recirculation system in place?

Comment: Is there a recirculating pump somewhere on the system, or is it just set up for thermosiphon?

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd or recirculating pipe on a hot water system makes the water hot when you open the tap rather than waiting. Cap it off and find the pump and turn it off.

You may want to re install it at a later time there are multiple ways to do this to maintain instant hot water at the tap but that will be a separate question and answer. I would cap it off and if possible isolate the pump and turn off the power to the pump.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not actually hooked up to a boiler...your heating system. Then yes, and I agree with Ed Beal, it can be capped and re-activated later.

If it is part of the heating system, then this operation must be performed by a knowlegeable HVAC technician. Your disconnection can cause unforeseen consequences of major expense.

Although, if the pipe's really for a re-circulation setup...quite a rare find. Then, I would strongly suggest you keep it as an active part of the plumbing. The cost and convenience savings can be very worthwhile.